# Madhvacharya and Nigamanda Mahadesikan

Tags: scripture, madhvacharya, vedanta-desika

I heard from one Madva Achar that Madhvacharya [Acharya for Raghavendra disciples] and Nigamanda Mahadesikan [Acharya for Vadakalai sect Vaishnavites] met and discussed various topics related to Vaisnavism and Madhvism during their period. Any scriptural evidence for this.

Comment: I know that Vedanta Desikan moderated a debate in which Madhvacharya's shishya Akshobhya Tirtha defeated the Advaita Acharya Vidyaranya.  But I've never heard of Vedanta Desikan meeting Madhvacharya himself.  But let me see if I can find any information on it.

Comment: @keshav--But the achar told  when I went for performing monthly masikam for my father----

Comment: It is captured in stone at Mulbagal

Comment: @Sudarsan You're talking about the debate, right, not Vedanta Desikan meeting Madhvacharya?